# python : error while saving image from url

Tags: python, django, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I need to save image from url, with Django.
So I did like the tutorial says, but I get a strange error.

```
page = requests.get(url)
if page.status_code != 200 or not page.content:
assert 0, 'can\'t download article image'
image = image_content_file(page.content)
article.image.save('%i.jpg' % article.pk, image, save=False)
```

My Article Model :

```
class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   content = models.TextField(blank=True)
   image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='upload/article_image')
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

I have created `upload/article_image` folder and set its rights to 777

My `image_content_file` function :

```
def image_content_file(img_content):
    input_file = StringIO(img_content)
    output_file = StringIO()
    img = Image.open(input_file)
    if img.mode != "RGB":
        img = img.convert("RGB")
    img.save(output_file, "JPEG")
    return ContentFile(output_file.getvalue())
```

But I get this error

```
image = image_content_file(page.content)
  File "/home/yital9/webservers/binarybits/binarybits/../binarybits/utils/img.py", line 24, in image_content_file
    img.save(output_file, "JPEG")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 399, in _getencoder
    return apply(encoder, (mode,) + args + extra)
TypeError: function takes at most 9 arguments (11 given)
```

Can you give me any advice what is the problem?

Comment: why don't you use urllib.urlretrieve("http://example.com/img.jpg") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do what you need:

```
import urllib2
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

content = ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
article.image.save('%i.jpg' % article.pk, content, save=True)
```

Instead if you just want to download an image from the web is better to do this:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
urlretrieve(url, '%i.jpg' % article.pk)
```

Comment: This has absolutely no relation with the problem.

Comment: Why? That's the way in python to download files from a url. If I know a better way to solve a problem, according to me is relevant to point it out.

Comment: If you look at the code, he is converting his picture to the RGB colorspace, and saves it after that. This is when the error is happening, not when he tries to download it. **But you are right, his method of downloading the picture is weird, and it would be easier using your way**. I wrote my first comment too fast, sorry.

Comment: can you please give me an example of saving this image ? foo = urlretrieve(data['image'], '/home/yital9/webservers/binarybits/binarybits/media/upload/article_image/%i.jpg' % article.pk)
            article.image.save('%i.jpg' % article.pk, foo) -- this code save image in folder, but dont save to model

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, check the answer now

Answer (score 0):

To make it work in Python 3, you have to use

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=filepath)
```